# How to read specify columns from file in GNU OCTAVE?

Tags: matlab, file-io, octave

In GNU OCTAVE,
I have input file like this, and i have to read only first and second columns and store to variable. . This is only small part of my file. When so, i can not read whole file and cut a column that i need. I should read only what i need, to save a memory.

```
1 2 1 1015887601
1 3 1 1015887601
1 4 1 1015887601
1 5 1 1015887601
1 6 1 1015887601
1 7 1 1015887601
1 8 1 1015887601
1 9 1 1015887601
2 10 1 1015887601
2 11 1 1015887601
2 12 1 1015887601
3 13 1 1015887601
3 14 1 1015887601
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out [dlmread](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dlmread.html). Octave has the [same function](http://octave.sourceforge.net/octave/function/dlmread.html), it seems to do what you need.

Something like:

```
dlmread('yourfile.txt', ' ', 'A1..Bn') % replace n with the size of the file
```

Comment: Or you can use the `range` parameter which is might be more appropriate. `M = dlmread(filename, delimiter, range) `

Comment: Why do you not add the link to Octave's `dlmread()` instead of Matlab's?

Comment: @Pokey McPokerson
how can i get file size to replace n

Comment: Hi kkuilla, I used the Matlab link because it was very descriptive and had nice examples. The functions work exactly the same way as far as I can tell.

Comment: TNeykov, it seems like your data is fairly predictable? You could keep reading in blocks until you encounter a 0. Or if you're expecting 0s, you can set the "empty value" field to -1 (see the Octave function link in the updated answer).